# Form validation - unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, list, validation

I need help with a form validator. It validates everything like text and such fine, but I need it to validate whether an unordered list has at least 1 element/item in it.

My initial idea was to count the childNodes in the unordered list, but using .childNodes.length did not work. I'm not sure why, possibly because I have jQuery intermingled in my javascript functions?

Here is an example of the validation function for a text string:

```
 function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
    if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
         o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
     updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
         min + " and " + max + "." );
     return false;
  } else {
    return true;
       }
 }
```

Here is what my unordered form validation function was (doesn't work):

```
function checkTags( t ) {
if (t.childNodes.length < 1) {
    t.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
    updateTips( "Add at least 1 genre/subgenre." );
    return false;
}
else {
        return true;
}
}
```

The unordered list is populated by the user, after selecting values from a select list and clicking a javascript link, if that matters. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `t` is a jQuery object, try

```
if (!t.children().length) {
    t.addClass('ui-state-error');
}
```

here's a link for your reference: http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 0):

If *t* is an element, then *t.childNodes* includes all child nodes, including text nodes, as well as element nodes. Many browsers insert empty text nodes in the DOM to represent whitespace in the markup, so in some browsers, the folloing div:

```
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

has 3 child nodes, in others only one. You can check for child element nodes using:

```
if (element.getElementsByTagName('*').length) // element has child element nodes
```